# Построить список, состоящий из n элементов, каждый из которых является максимальным среди элементов списков с соответствующим номером

Tags: python

Дано натуральное число n>=2, список списков, состоящий из n элементов по n чисел в элементе.Пример: [[1,2,3], [4,7,2],[0,-7,1]]. Результат: [4,7,3].
Пояснение:cравниваются сначала первые числа вложенных списков 1,4,0 в результате находим 4,а потом соответственно проделываем те же действия с вторыми числами.(Если я не правильно понял,прошу поправить)

Я не могу решить не сколько проблем для решения этой задачи:Во-первых как сравнивать числа вложенных списков по порядку как в пояснении,во-вторых как сделать так,чтобы сравнивались двухзначные и более числа,cравнивались с минусом
Вот то,что мне пока удалось:

```
N = int(input("Введите количество списков в списке:"))
arr = [ list(input("Введите числа во вложенном списке:")) for i in range (N)] 
print("Полученный список списков:",arr)
d = len(arr)
m = list()
try:
    for i in range(d):
        b = arr.pop(i)
        print("Вложенный список",b)
        d = list(b)
        d = max(b)
        m.append(d)
        print(m)
except:
    print("перебор элементов закончился")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** при вводе чисел, элементы списков надо преобразовать из строк в числа:

```
arr = [list(map(int, input("Введите числа во вложенном списке:").split())) 
       for i in range (N)]
```

PS функция `input()` - возвращает строку (для Python .x)

---

решение в функциональном стриле:

```
In [27]: items = [[1,2,3], [4,7,2],[0,-7,1]]

In [28]: res = list(map(max, zip(*items)))

In [29]: print(res)
[4, 7, 3]
```

---

`zip(*items)` - транспонирует матрицу:

```
In [30]: print(list(zip(*items)))
[(1, 4, 0), (2, 7, -7), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Спасибо,но хотелось бы узнать как сравнивать не только однозначные числа,но и двузначные,и с минусом

Comment: у меня число -234 разделяется на элементы '-', '2', '3', '4' и в результате программа не правильно работает,если я в генераторе списков поставлю прямоугольные скобки,то у меня введённое число с пробелами будет как одно число,но я могу подразумевать,что я ввожу не одно,а несколько

Comment: @Noob_Prog, у вас проблема с вводом элементов. `input()` - возвращает строку

Comment: Спасибо,и последний вопрос,и тогда все проблемы будут решены как сравнивать только числа не смотря на то,что я ввожу не только числа,но и буквы

Comment: @Noob_Prog, нет, при попытке преобразовать "буквы" в число вы получите исключение. Попробуйте выполнить: `int("123oops!")`

Comment: Извините,я неправильно выразился,как игнорировать буквы при вводе и сравнивать только числа

Comment: @Noob_Prog, задайте отдельный вопрос. Вы пытаетесь в одном SO вопросе получить ответы на все вопросы, которые возникли у вас при решении вашей задачи. Это противоречит идеологии SO. Подозреваю, что следующим вопросом будет: как заставить пользователя ввести нужное количество чисел...

Comment: Я понял,хорошо,а вам как самому активному пользователю большое спасибо и поставлю галочку)

Answer (score 1):

> Как заставить пользователя ввести квадратную матрицу, состоящую из целых чисел, игнорируя
>   неправильный/ошибочный ввод?

```
def input_int(text):
    while True:
        try:
            inp = input(text)
            return int(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print("Ошибка: '{}' - не является целым числом! Попробуйте ещё раз...".format(inp))

N = int(input("Введите количество списков в списке:"))
arr = []

for i in range(1, N+1):
    tmp = []
    for j in range(1, N+1):
        tmp.append(input_int("введите A[{},{}]: ".format(i, j)))
    arr.append(tmp)
```

---

```
Введите количество списков в списке:3
введите A[1,1]: 1
введите A[1,2]: 2oops!
Ошибка: '2oops!' - не является целым числом! Попробуйте ещё раз...
введите A[1,2]: 2
введите A[1,3]: 3
введите A[2,1]: 4
введите A[2,2]: 7
введите A[2,3]: 2
введите A[3,1]: 0
введите A[3,2]: -7
введите A[3,3]: 1
```

---

```
print(arr)
#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 7, 2], [0, -7, 1]]
```

Comment: Извините,но в программе появляется сообщение invalid syntax

Comment: @Noob_Prog, на какую строчку кода ругается?

Comment: Не высвечивается сейчас,но вроде на седьмую было

Comment: @Noob_Prog, какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: версия 3.4.3 сейчас

Comment: @Noob_Prog, `f-string` появились в Python 3.6. Переделал ответ с использованием `str.format()` - это будет работать и на старых версиях Python